# C# standalone application with java backend webservice

Tags: c#, java, web-services, excel-dna

I am new to C# (still learning). My problem statement is that i have to build a C# plugin for excel. The backend of the application is spring based Restful service implemented using Restlet.

Can i leverage the same service and make calls from the proposed C# standalone app (the excel plugin)? if so can someone point me to some sample c# client webservice code?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can.

Just add a [Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668183.aspx)

And then with a using statement you can connect and make calls.

Make sure you also [Don't use using](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197531/Do-not-use-using-for-WCF-Clients) to wrap your calls.  Use a helper class, and even then wrap it in a try/catch

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am using only a C# client to make the calls is it still relevant? will i be using WCF? Sorry since i am new i do not know.

Comment: @Shah A service reference is a service reference.  If it's a webservice you're connecting to, then it's a webservice you need to wire up in your application.  I missed the part about restful when I wrote this, but I don't think rest services are much different.